# ora-01036: illegal variable name/number insert python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, pandas, oracle-11g

Tengo el siguiente dataframe

```
 df2 = {name: ['PEPE'], id: [1], stage:[3], order: [43], last_name: ['ARAUZ']}
```

Luego la convierto a un array para insertarlo a la base de datos, con el método de pytho `tolist()`, asi que queda asi:

```
df2_list = [['PEPE', 1, 3, 43, 'ARAUZ']...]
```

Donde :

```
name = :1, id= :2, number_stage= :3, order= :4, last_name= :5
```

Así que intento insertar a la base de datos el dataframe, pero con unos datos ya previamente definidos en el script, ademas de los campos, que permite nulos, pero me manda ese error y no entiendo por qué, es como si una de esas variables no fuese permitidas,

Me podrian ayudar por favor, muy agradecido con sus comentarios.

```
import cx_Oracle
    
    conn = cx_Oracle.connet(connection)
    try: 
       cur = conn.cursor()
       spt = "INSERT INTO user.table_name values('references',:1,'text',7,6,'F','A','Y','','','','',:2,:3,2,:4);"
       cur.executemany(spt, df2)
       print("executed!")
    except Exception as err:
       print('Error', err)
    else:
       conn.commit()
```

Comment: Te recomiendo usar el método to_sql() de pandas para hacer el insert, no necesitarías modificar la estructura de datos y directamente harías un insert basado en tu dataframe.

Comment: Pero en el insert necesito definir valores previos, dado a que son requeridos en la tabla